# Try to start library project Activity

Tags: android, android-library

I have a library project and Main project and I try to start the activity that is defined in library project from main project.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("isr.LAUNCH");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.ISR", "com.ISR.activity.CameraActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But I receive the following exception:

```
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=isr.LAUNCH cmp=com.ISR/.activity.CameraActivity } from ProcessRecord{40aa7178 29217:com.ssbs.sw.SWE/10094} (pid=29217, uid=10094) requires null
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1351)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1374)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at com.ssbs.sw.IR.view.MainActivity$1$1.onMenuItemClick(MainActivity.java:58)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at com.ssbs.sw.SWE.actionbarV5.menu.MenuButtonHelper$1.onClick(MenuButtonHelper.java:108)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2492)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9087)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3740)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
05-14 17:13:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(29217):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my manifest from library project:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity android:name=".activity.CameraActivity" android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="isr.LAUNCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**
My main project manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

**EDIT 2**
I have resolved my problem by coping to my main application manifest definition of called activity (but I would like to know if I can do this without adding this definition):

```
<activity android:name="com.ISR.activity.CameraActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="isr.LAUNCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And now I can start my activity with following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("isr.LAUNCH");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: move the permissions to your main project as opposed to your library project?

Comment: @NirvanaTikku I have the same permission in my main project manifest

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding both projects just in case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manifest for your main app must contain all Activity definitions it wishes to use. They are not required in the library project as they are not called from there.

Any activity definitions you have in your library manifest actually do nothing at all.

Update: You can now merge manifest files as other answers have mentioned.

Comment: And there are no way to start library project activity from main proj without defining it in main proj manifest? And why I receive security exception?

Comment: correct. All activities you wish to use must be defined in your app manifest. Even if you use Admob, the activities in the Admob library must be registered in your own manifest otherwise the system cannot launch them.

Answer (score 12):

You can actually declare everything you want in the library's Manifest and then in your main project declare

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

In your project.properties. What it does is actually merge your Manifests and you can see the resulting Manifest in your bin folder.

Comment: it si for newer ADT (version 20 preview 3) and above and you need to add it to your project.properties file of your application project.

Comment: It was indeed added in SDK Tools, Revision 20, but that doesn't mean you can't use it to compile previous apps. [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) I did say it was to include in the project.properties of the application project. Cheers!

Comment: how to configure manifestmerger when project.properties is now gradle.properties?