# Can't open Activity from other module

Tags: android, android-activity, module, android-manifest, activitynotfoundexception

I've added a reference to a new module and try to open an `Activity` from it. 
It `throws` an `Exception` that says:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class{
>       com.giljulio.imagepicker.ui/com.giljulio.imagepicker.ui.ImagePickerActivity
>       };

have you declared this activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml?`

Do I need to add anything else beside reference the new `module`?

Comment: Did you in fact add the activity to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: You can check this. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545725/try-to-start-library-project-activity

Comment: declare ImagePickerActivity activity in the Manifest...

<activity android:name="com.giljulio.imagepicker.ui.ImagePickerActivity"/>

Comment: Thanks.
It was really not define in my AndroidManifest, 
But, maybe I don't understand something, I want to use a github project ( https://github.com/giljulio/android-multiple-image-picker ), If I import this module to my project I need to call it's main activity ? when I do so, it throw an exception that it doen not recognize some of it R.id's.

the module manifest is :
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </application>

Comment: I investigated this issue in the following article and proposed a practical solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77384164/10090030

Answer (score 6):

You have to define in gradle dependencies(in module where you want to call another module activity):

```
dependencies{
     ...
     compile project(':yourModuleName')
     ...
}
```

After adding this sync the gradle and now can you use the activity in the module.

Comment: Do you edit the build.gradle file directly, or is there a dialog in Android Studio to use?

Answer (score 2):

User like this. This will help you

```
Intent intent = null;
try {
    intent = new Intent(this, 
       Class.forName("ir.test.testlibary1.HelloWorldActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am a few years late.

The issue is not that you don't have the gradle dependency as @arpit suggested, it seems you report a runtime exception. Also, what @Aman suggested will help with the handling the exception, it will just not help you start the activity.

If understood correctly, you have a multi-module app (let's say A-app module and B-lib module) and need to call another lib-module(C) from one B.

If that is the case, you need to declare that library's activity(C) in your module's(B) Manifest.xml, inside the  tag.

If it has not already been setup, you also need to enable manifest merger.