# Start app activity from android phone module

Tags: android

I have 2 modules in my app: app module (which is the original module) and a second module which hold an activity.

I want to launch the main activity which is in my second module when clicking on a button and get back to my app module's main activity when clicking on another button.
[image: Project architecture]

I've tried to do the following but got a ClassNotFoundException:

```
packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.secondmodule")?.let {
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

and that:

```
val intent = Intent(this, Class.forName("com.example.secondmodule.MainActivity"))
        startActivity(intent)
```

and that:

```
startActivity(Intent("com.example.secondmodule"))
```

but nothing seems to work, is it even possible ?
What can I do to obtain this behavior ?

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429784/how-to-start-an-activity-in-another-module-explicitly)

Comment: Though i guess you said you tried the answer from there...

Comment: Can you show Manifest for second module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way

```
    // Get an instance of PackageManager
    val pm = applicationContext.packageManager

    // Initialize a new Intent
    val intent:Intent? = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)

    // Add category to intent
    intent?.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)

   // If intent is not null then launch the app
   if(intent != null) {
     applicationContext.startActivity(intent)
   }
```